# How to define probabilities with underneath text?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I want to use probability where I can write some text underneath it. I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[adversary,
            asymptotics,
            complexity,
            landau,
            mm,
            operators,
            probability,
            sets]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,,
            linkcolor=black,
            citecolor=blue,
            backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equation}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
    
\newcommand{\dist}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\ensuremath{\bm{#1}}}
 \renewcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\renewcommand{\prob}[2]{\Pr_{#1}\mleft[\,#2\,\mright]}
\newcommand{\cprob}[3]{\Pr_{#1}\mleft[\,#2\;\middle\vert\;#3\,\mright]}
 \newcommand{\vect}[1]{\ensuremath{\bm{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
For $r > 0$, $n \geq 1$ and $k > 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \prob{\vect{z} \gets \dist_{\ZZ^n,r}}{\norm{\vect{z}} > kr\sqrt{n/(2\pi)}} < k^n \cdot \exp(n/2 \cdot (1 - k^2)).
\end{align*}
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

But this throws the following error: "Missing delimiter (. inserted)." on Overleaf. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: @campa How about now?

Comment: Now I get no error at all.

Answer (score 1):

You example is full of errors

- the lemma env is not defined
- `\norm` does not already exists so `\renewcommand` fails
- `\mleft` and `\mright` needs a package you haven't loaded
- `\prob` is not already defined so `\renewcommand` fails.
- `\ZZ` is not defined

Do not just ignore compilation errors. The first error I get is the one for `\norm` not something related to delimiters. Remember to read the error messages from top to bottom as errors can and will accumulate.

After fixing this I get

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy all the packages I'm using. I updated the question.

Comment: @pixel your updated example compiles just fine for me ad gives almost the same image.

Comment: Hmm interesting, Overleaf compiles as well but throws errors regarding `mleftright`.

Comment: @pixel I get no error in Overleaf either.

Comment: @pixel exactly which texlive and engine are you using in overleaf?

Comment: I'm using pdflatex version 2023 within Overleaf.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the log of your compilation in overleaf on the exact example posted here? As campa mentioned, they have no errors in OL.

Comment: Okay it seems the error was in previous places where `prob` was used, since I modified the macro afterwards. Now is all good. But it seems I cannot delete the question. Maybe I can delete if you delete the answer.